# Ouch. Dark mode?

Tags: feature-request, design

Do we know when non Stack Overflow communities will get dark mode? I have clicked around in the user profile/settings area looking for this feature.

Comment: MSE: [Plans for dark mode for all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359739/plans-for-dark-mode-for-all-stack-exchange-sites)